# programmitacly get related nodes by terms

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, entities

Im trying to get nodes related to a node in my module

i found https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7

its only accepting 1 TID ... i mean 1 term for query related nodes

i want to pass all node terms and find related nodes by TERMS not TERM ... (some kind of aggregate query)

plz help

Comment: Why don't you just loop thrue all your terms then?
foreach ($voc as $term({$nodes[] =taxonomy_select_nodes($term)}

Comment: Yeah, just write a wrapper taxonomy_select_nodes_multiple_terms($array) that loops through your array and calls the function you describe above.

Comment: @Robin   u both fail ... i want to get similarity by the score of included tags ...  you know what is similarity?